# What's the trick to the cart race?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

Toward the beginning of Assassin's Creed: Revelations, Ezio is chasing down a Templar captain in a horse-drawn cart. Eventually, he catches up and tries to destroy the captain's cart by smashing into it in a way that does more damage to the other cart than it does to his own. There are rough areas of the road that do damage to either cart if it passes over them, so the other trick is to avoid these while luring your enemy into them.

The first time I tried this, I caught up to the enemy cart and basically just mashed the left stick to the right, swinging my cart at my enemy's, jostling and smashing. I went over the rough patches a couple of times, and so did my enemy. My cart lost "health" more quickly than his, and then it failed and I had to restart the mission.

The second time I tried this, I caught up to the enemy cart and basically just mashed the left stick to the right, swinging my cart at my enemy's, jostling and smashing. I went over the rough patches a couple of times, and so did my enemy. His cart lost "health" more quickly than mine, and so I made it past the invisible finish line that triggered the next cutscene.

I played the game the exact same way both times, going into the race with the same level of cart health. Is there a trick to this race that I stumbled upon by accident, or is it basically just a crapshoot whether or not you win?

Comment: The hint text as I was doing this suggested that 'winding up' first would do more damage - that is, swinging hard to the left then back to the right.  It didn't really seem to do too much good, though, mostly because there really isn't any room to prep for it.

Comment: I think another hint text said you had to travel a greater distance, so simply swinging back and forth quickly isn't effective. You should make broad sweeps instead and try to push them over stones, without getting hit yourself off course!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you smash into your enemy's cart, you have slightly less than a second before the horses start going left again.
The object isn't to destroy your enemy's cart, but to survive the road ahead. I finished it without destroying the enemy cart.

All you need to do is hit your enemy's cart right before you cross some rubble. You'll dodge the rubble, and then the horses pull left on open road instead of the broken bits of road.

Comment: Same response as me, but clearer. Vote up!

Comment: Hm. Yeah. It was annoying how the goal seemed to be "destroy the enemy's cart", but really the goal was "survive until the invisible finish line and then fall off the road anyway during a cutscene". Oh well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Theres a part of luck in that Sequence, I'll give you that.

The trick is to time the places where you'll kinda stick with the other cart to dodge the rubble.

I didn't really like that part for that lack of strategy in use.

Answer (score 3):

You don't destroy the enemy's cart; you simply survive.

Leandros will try and ram you if you get too close. Keep your distance and don't go in the offensive. Steer clear of the rocky patches and you should be fine.
When you reach a certain point, a cutscene will trigger. Leandros will yell to his guards, one of which will throw a grenade under your carriage, causing the carriage and Ezio to go flying over the canyon. As a result, Ezio is severely injured, and the mission "The Wounded Eagle" will begin.
So you're not meant to destroy Leandros' carriage. I do not even know if it's possible.